# Targeting dynamic class names in css/scss or JavaScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

In my rails application I have two models, Users and Goals. A User can have Many Goals, and a Goal belongs to a User. I have a page that lists all of a users Goals in the users show page. This is done using a .each loop, and in this loop I have created a dynamic class name that puts the goal_id into the class name.

I want to be able to target these individual classes in my css/scss folder so that I can, for example, have only the first goal be highlighted when I hover over it.

app/views/users/show.html.erb

```
<div class="user-goals-mouse-events">
<% @user.goals.each do |goal| %>
    <%= link_to goal_path(goal), class: "user-goals-hover-#{goal.id}" do %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h2 class="color-light-blue"><%= goal.name %></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 user-goals-description">
                    <h4><%= goal.description %></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h6 class="hide-username-<%= goal.id %>"><%= @user.username %></h6>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The Scss is not working currently but it may help show what i'm attempting to do.
app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss

```
.user-goals-mouse-events > a {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: black;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    //background-color: black;
    &:hover {
        background-color: #26AEFF;
        color: gold;
    }
}

.user-goals-mouse-events > div > h6 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.color-light-blue {
    color: #26AEFF;
    &:hover {
        color: white;
    }
}
```

If a better solution to this problem is done a different way (e.g. with javascript) then please let me know as I want to do it the most efficient way.

Comment: Do you only want the first goal to be highlighted when hovered over?

Comment: I would like it to highlight whichever goal I am currently hovering over, so if i'm hovering over the goal with i.d = 1, then I would like to apply the hover rules to the class "user-goals-hover-1". If i then move my mouse down to the next goal with i.d of 2, then the class of "user-goals-hover-2" should be highlighted, and "user-goals-hover-1" will no longer be highlighted.

Comment: Is any of your scss working anywhere in your app?

Comment: Yes the above scss is the only part which is not working properly. And actually when I hover over the user-goals-mouse-events element the text is turning gold (but the background is not turning blue, and there are no borders)

Comment: Thanks for the help i really appreciate it. I'm not sure how it is incorrect though? In the console it is coming through correctly and the links all work and direct to the correct pages. It is rendering in html as <a class="user-goals-hover-1" href="/goals/1">..</a>, then the next is with a 2 etc. Is there a better way I can write this?

Comment: If you are saying it is incorrect due to me target a different class in the SCSS, that was because I tried to target all 'a' childs, underneath the user-goals-mouse-events parent. If i could replace that with a class of "user-goals-hover-#{goal.id}" that would be ideal but I couldn't work that out

Comment: I can't find a way to target my dynamic class names in html so that when I implement a rule in scss (such as hovering over the element) it will be applied to that single element. At the moment (when on a users page with 4 different goals) I can't target each specific goal individually (unless I was to write out in scss   .user-goals-hover-1, .user-goals-hover-2, .user-goals-hover-3, .user-goals-hover-4). It either doesn't work or I can only get it applied to the whole block (so all 4 goals get highlighted at the same time). Hopefully that makes more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the attribute-value-begins-with selector:

```
a[class^=user-goals-hover] {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  //background-color: black;

  &:hover {
    background-color: #26AEFF;
    color: gold;
  }
}
```

Comment: It works! The only thing I changed was adding a new div between the .each loop, and the link_to, with the class name "user-goals-hover-<%=goal.id%>" instead of in the link_to as before (it would not work when in there). Therefore in the scss file i targeted it with 'div[class^=user-goals-hover]' and it works great. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

@hashrocket answer is good, but I'd advise to be more explicit on your classes. It is a code smell when you need a class *both* for styling and for targeting.

Yes, there is such a thing as code smell in CSS too! :)

I would have a constant class for styling and a dynamic one or even a completely different attribute for targeting:

```
<%= link_to goal_path(goal), class: "user-goals", data: {goal_id: goal.id} do %>
```

which would render as

```
<a href="/goals/42" class="user-goals" data-goal-id="42">
```

and the css would just be

```
.user-goals {
  //...

  &:hover {
    //...
  }
}
```